# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException running Kotlin jar library

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I am creating REST API for ClamAV https://hub.docker.com/r/clamav/clamav and I try to use java clamav-client https://github.com/cdarras/clamav-client for this purpose.
I have built clamav-client and include produced JAR file into my project in IntelliJ IDEA Community edition. I have added this JAR file into dependencies/classpath.
But when I run project I get exception on line `ClamavClient client = new ClamavClient("localhost")`:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at xyz.capybara.clamav.ClamavClient.<init>(ClamavClient.kt) ~[clamav-client-2.1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.example.clamavapi.controllers.ClamavApiController.scan(ClamavApiController.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
```

clamav-client is written in Kotlin so I have tried to create Kotlin project for my REST API too

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.9.20</kotlin.version>
    </properties>
```

but exception still remain with little difference it crash on next line `ScanResult scanResult = client.scan(inputstream)`:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mu.KLogging
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at xyz.capybara.clamav.commands.Command.<clinit>(Command.kt) ~[clamav-client-2.1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at xyz.capybara.clamav.ClamavClient.scan(ClamavClient.kt:106) ~[clamav-client-2.1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.example.clamavapi.controllers.ClamavApiController.scan(ClamavApiController.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
```

What I am missing and what I have to do to run project correctly.
Thanks in advance.